# Splitting Long php generated HTML table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I use a `MySql` query to select data from my DB and then print it in the form of a `HTML Table`. It works perfectly, fine but sometimes the table consists of hundreds of rows and the webpage looks incredibly akward. Is there a way to split the table side by side into 2 or 3 halves.

> **Present Output**

[image]

> **Desired output**

[image]

> **PHP**

```
<?php
....
echo "<h3>Classes attended :</h3>";
echo "<table class='dates' border='1'>";

 foreach ($results as $dates) {

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'>";
    echo $dates->db_date;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width='50%'>";
    echo $dates->day_name;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

What would be the best way to achieve it?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Paginate your results better, that's the standard practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to determine in your loop if the loop index is divisible by a certain number using something like this:

```
echo "<h3>Classes attended :</h3>";
echo "<table class='dates' border='1'>";
$rowCount = 1;
$numRows = count($results);
$maxRows = 12;

foreach ($results as $dates) {

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'>";
    echo $dates->db_date;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width='50%'>";
    echo $dates->day_name;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if($rowCount % $maxRows == 0 && $rowCount != $numRows)  {
       echo "</table><table class='dates' border='1'>";
    }
    $rowCount ++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

That's the basics of doing this. Basically in your loop you're testing each index to see if it's divisible by $maxRows, and if so then you're going to close your table and open a new one.  You'll have to add the styling to place the tables side by side.

If you wanted to expand upon this concept you can set $maxRows to be an evaluation of $numRows.  For instance if you wanted to split the items as close as possible to half in order to show just two tables, you could do... `$numRows = count($results); $maxRows = round($numRows / 2);`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Robert Wade's answer:

```
<?php
....
echo "<h3>Classes attended :</h3>";

 $i=0;
 $maxRows=10;
 foreach ($results as $dates) {
    $a=$i/$maxRows == 0 ? "<table class='dates' border='1'>":"";
    $b=$i/$maxRows == 0 ? "</table>":"";

    echo $a;
    echo "<tr><td width='50%'>";
    echo $dates->db_date;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width='50%'>";
    echo $dates->day_name;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo $b;

    $i++;
}
?>
```

At last, add some css style to the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for splitting your results. Or instead of displaing a lot of tables next to each other you can make pagination and get only some range in your query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` LIMIT 5, 10
```

Selects 10 rows beggining from row 5. Now, when you change your page, just change limit values.